# Why is my wordpress showing theme documentation at the homepage?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Its been a while i used my blog but am surprised to check now and see theme documentation showing at the homepage.

See here: [Link of website with the issue](https://www.loadedcamp.net/blog)

[image: This is the screenshot of the homepage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have uploaded the theme documentation in the blog folder.
And the index.html of the theme documentation is showing.Instead of your website.

Just rename the index.html, Your site will show up again